# Seg Fault Depending on Order of Pointer Assignment

Tags: c++, pointers

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  // ok by itself     
  int *ptr1;
  int a = 3;
  *ptr1 = a;

  // ok by itself        
  int *ptr2 = new int(4);
  delete ptr2;
}
```

This results in a seg fault, and I can't figure out why.  If either of the blocks are commented, it's okay.  If the second block is placed above the first block, it's also okay.  What's going on here?

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. Period. Fix the bug (don't use the value of a variable until you assign it a value) and the mystery will go away.

Comment: Ask yourself "what does `ptr1` point to when it is dereferenced"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot dereference `ptr1` because it's uninitialized.

With that said, `*ptr1 = a` is incorrect, and you're getting *undefined behavior*, which means that this code may or may not work as one expects.

Comment: I know I'm not initializing the pointer, but doesn't `*ptr1 = a` just mean, "whatever `ptr1` was pointing to, now let it point to `a`"?  It seems even if I don't initialize it, it's still pointing to something.

Comment: @bcf, no, it's not pointing to anything as it's _uninitialized_. You can only dereference pointers that points to memory _your program owns_, and you get a segmentation fault otherwise.